# What software can I use to invert txt list IP-ranges? (not a reverse DNS lookup)

Tags: ip, utorrent

This is a blocklist, but I want to have only IP in the list to be allowed.

instead of:

```
1.2.3.5-1.2.10.20
2.2.3.5-3.2.100.20,
```

I need:

```
0.0.0.0-1.2.3.4
1.2.10.21-2.2.3.4
3.2.100.21-255.255.255.255.
```

What program or script can I use to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You haven’t specified what operating system and tools you are using
or have access to. 
I’ll assume that you’re on a *nix system and can use a shell script. 
The example you gave might be easy to handle by simple string manipulation,
but realizing that the next address after 42.17.255.255 is 42.18.0.0
is a little tricky. 
I think the easiest way to do this is to convert the addresses
to 32-bit integers, do simple arithmetic on them, and convert them back. 
So here’s a shell script to do that:

```
#!/bin/sh
ip_to_dec()
{
        octets=( $(echo "$1" | tr "." " ") )
        echo $(( (((${octets[0]}*256)+${octets[1]})*256+${octets[2]})*256+${octets[3]} ))
}

dec_to_ip()
{
        n=$1
        d=$((n%256))
        n=$((n/256))
        c=$((n%256))
        n=$((n/256))
        b=$((n%256))
        a=$((n/256))
        echo "$a.$b.$c.$d"
}

my_args=( $(echo "$1 $2" | tr "-" " ") )
for ((i=0; i<4 ; i++))
do
        my_arg_dec[i]=$(ip_to_dec "${my_args[i]}")
done
my_arg_dec[0]=$(( my_arg_dec[0]-1 ))
my_arg_dec[1]=$(( my_arg_dec[1]+1 ))
my_arg_dec[2]=$(( my_arg_dec[2]-1 ))
my_arg_dec[3]=$(( my_arg_dec[3]+1 ))

echo "0.0.0.0-$(dec_to_ip ${my_arg_dec[0]})" \
     "$(dec_to_ip ${my_arg_dec[1]})-$(dec_to_ip ${my_arg_dec[2]})" \
     "$(dec_to_ip ${my_arg_dec[3]})-255.255.255.255"
```

It uses the `array_name=( $(echo "something" | tr "some_character" " ") )` trick
to break text apart at delimiters into words,
and assign the resulting word list to an array. 
It does what I described above:
converts the IP addresses to 32-bit decimal numbers,
does trivial (`-1`/`+1`) arithmetic on them, and converts them back.

If you’re going to use this for real, you should add error checking.